# Updated state is not reflected in my onPress event

Tags: typescript, react-native, swiper.js, mobile-development

I'm trying to implement a slider in my react native app. I'm using the [react-native-web-swiper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-web-swiper) library. I'm using the useState hook to monitor which index the swiper is on. In the onIndexChanged() prop of the swiper, I update the state (current index). My problem is that the onPress event for my swiper components doesn't use the updated state.

```
export default ({ navigation, route }: any) => {
  const pages = DataController.getData().onboardingPages;

  const swiper = useRef<Swiper>(null);

  const [index, setIndex] = useState<number>(0);

  const handleNextButton = () => {
    console.log("INDEX IN BUTTON PRESS", index); // index is zero here?? it should be 0,1,2, or 3
    if (index !== pages.length - 1) {
      swiper.current?.goToNext();
    } else {
      navigation.replace("Landing");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useeffect called with index ", index); // index is correct here
  }, []);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log("uselayouteffect called with index ", index); // index is correct here
    if (index !== pages.length - 1) {
      navigation.setOptions({
        headerRight: () => (
          <Text
            style={styles.skip}
            onPress={() => navigation.replace("Landing")}
          >
            Skip
          </Text>
        ),
      });
    } else {
      navigation.setOptions({
        headerRight: undefined,
      });
    }
  }, [index]);

  return (
    <Swiper
      ref={swiper}
      controlsProps={{
        prevTitle: "",
        nextTitle: "",
        prevPos: false,
        nextPos: false,
      }}
      // controlsEnabled={false}
      loop={false}
      onIndexChanged={index => {
        console.log("index changed to ", index);
        setIndex(index);
      }}
    >
      {pages.map(item => {
        return (
          <OnboardingPage
            key={item.pageNumber}
            text={item.text}
            image={item.image}
            handleNextButton={handleNextButton}
          />
        );
      })}
    </Swiper>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  skip: {
    marginRight: 10,
    fontFamily: "an-regular",
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: "normal",
    fontStyle: "normal",
    lineHeight: 26,
    letterSpacing: -0.2,
    color: Colours.P_80,
  },
});
```